# What exactly select this XPath query?

Tags: java, xml, xpath, xml-parsing, jdom

I am pretty new in XPath in Java and I have the following doubt related to this code that I found into a class on which I have to work:

```
public String getApplicationParameter(ApplicationParameter parameter) {
    Element n;
    XPath xPath;

    try {
        xPath = XPath.newInstance("//root/settings/" + parameter.toString().replace("_", "-") );
        n = (Element) xPath.selectSingleNode(CONFIG_DOCUMENT);
    } catch (JDOMException e) {
        return "";
    }

    if(n == null){
        return "";
     }
     return n.getText();
  }
```

Where the **ApplicationParameter** input parameter of the previous method is this **enum** that is declared in the same class:

```
public enum ApplicationParameter {
    cache_size,
    restub_days,
    upload_processes,
    download_processes,
    upload_bandwidth,
    download_bandwidth
}
```

And **CONFIG_DOCUMENT** is a **org.jdom.Document** that contain the XML on which the previous method work.

So my doubt is: what exactly select this **XPath query** ?

```
xPath = XPath.newInstance("//root/settings/" + parameter.toString().replace("_", "-") );
n = (Element) xPath.selectSingleNode(CONFIG_DOCUMENT);
```

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: Does the code work? If for example parameter is cache_size, then the string replacement will change that to "cache-size". xPath then specifies the element <cache-size> inside a <settings> element, which is inside the <root> element. With "//" meaning "root element of the document".

Comment: @splrs - //root actually means any element in the document called 'root', not just the root element of the document (which also would need to be called 'root'). Otherwise your comment is spot on.

Comment: Ahh yes you're right. Clearly I'm a bit rusty! +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given a document like this

```
<root>
  <settings>
    <cache-size id="THIS">120</cache-size>
    <restub-days>6</restub-days>  
  </settings>
</root>
```

the XPath expression selects the node I marked with ID `THIS`, and thus the whole method returns `120` (`n.getText()`). As a side note, it'd be better to use `Enum.name()` instead of `toString()` to get the name of the constant, because toString() can be overridden to return a different text.